# SyntaxError on input() supposedly in Python 3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I have a script for sending emails using `SMTP_SSL`. The code is working fine in PyCharm but in the terminal I get an error.

This is the code:

```
import  smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.googlemail.com:465")
mml=input("enter your email address :\n")
str(mml)
passr=input("enter your pass:\n")
str(passr)
s.login(mml,passr)
em = input("please type the email you want to send :\n")
str(em)
a = input("please type the message:\n")

    str(a)
    s.sendmail(mml,em,a)

print("\nEmail Was Sent..:)")
```

When I run this in my terminal its giving this after i enter the email:

```
enter your email address :
mahmoud.wizzo@gmail.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "medo.py", line 3, in <module>
mml=input("enter your email address :\n")
File "<string>", line 1
mahmoud.wizzo@gmail.com
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I am trying to put the email between quotes, e.g. "mahmoud.wizzo@gmail.com" its working fine.

How can I run my script in the terminal?

Comment: What are `str(mml)`, `str(passr)`, `str(em)`, and `str(a)` supposed to do?

Comment: Why are `str(a)` and `s.sendmail(mml,em,a)` indented? Whitespace is significant in Python—you should get an `IndentationError` here. Please make sure your question _exactly_ reflects your code. We have no way of knowing which errors are significant.

Comment: i dont have space before str(a) and s.sendmail(mml,em,a) just thats by wrong when posting

Comment: @Chris in the terminal when i type the email  i get the error 
but when type it  between "" its work fine

Comment: With that indentation error the script won't run. Please make sure the code in your question _exactly_ reflects the code on your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're running your script using Python 2 on the command line. [The behaviour of `input()` changed in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/354577).

Try running `python3 my_file.py` instead of `python my_file.py`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the way Python works. The problem you have is that `input` takes input from the user and then "executes" or "compiles" it so if you enter `4+9` in the input it will produce the number 13. Not the string `"4+9"`. So try using `raw_input()` in Python 2. You can also use `sys.stdin.readline()` to get a string I'm any Python version. Don't forget `import sys`.